# How to lower motherboard speaker volume

Tags: motherboard, speakers, front-panel

My motherboard has a small speaker connected in the front panel slot which beeps at every boot, however it's too loud. I wanted to keep the beep for diagnostic purposes, but just decrease its volume to the point I'd have to get near the case to hear it at boot.

I've thought about putting a resistor in series with the speaker, but I'm not very sure if that would do it. Is that the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely you'll be able to control the volume of the motherboard's built-in in diagnostic speaker with any settings.

Rewiring it might work, but an easier solution would be to place a bit of tape (e.g. electrician's tape) over the speaker. I've done this with various speakers/chimes and it works wonderfully.